# Listen a folder for changes java

Tags: java, listener, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to listen to folder or particular directory using Quartz api in java ? if possible and if u have code for it.Please do share

Comment: It should be possible to run a Quartz job periodically—say, every 10 seconds—to check a folder for any (new) files and act on them. Having said that, personally I think something like [Mule ESB's file transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/File+Transport+Reference) is more suited for things like that.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael : what is Mule ESB's file transport ? is it using Quartz ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using JDK 7, they provide new [APIs for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) api, and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are built-in jobs in Quartz to do... the job:

- [`DirectoryScanJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/jobs/DirectoryScanJob.html):

  > Inspects a directory and compares whether any files' "last modified dates" have changed since the last time it was inspected. If one or more files have been updated (or created), the job invokes a "call-back" method
- [`FileScanJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/jobs/FileScanJob.html)

  > Inspects a file and compares whether it's "last modified date" has changed since the last time it was inspected. If the file has been updated, the job invokes a "call-back" method